# Upload & download file in OneDrive using .Net Razor page

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-upload, razor-pages, onedrive

I want to upload & download excel file using C# razor page. Currently I have only username & password for that particular MS OneDrive account. I have checked few options but didn't worked any. Is there any other option to do so please let me know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which options have you already tried? What happened? Did you get error messages? If so, what were they?

Comment: Have tried below code snippet to get the drive details and then have passed the file "The expression cannot be evaluated.  common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate.  Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.MainError"                                                                                                           
var myDrive = await graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.GetAsync();
var uploadSession = await graphServiceClient.Drives[myDrive?.Id]
    .Items["root"]
    .ItemWithPath(oneDrivePath)
    .CreateUploadSession
    .PostAsync(uploadSessionRequestBody);